# Use Azure Appfabric on a local system

Tags: .net, wcf, client, azure

we want to use the azure appfabric for our software. But not every customer wants to buy an expensive azure account. Is it possibile to define and use an azure interface in our software but to connect the server and client local?

Mimefilt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may access Azure AppFabric from an on-premise app and take advantage of its services. However, you'll still need an Azure account for that, as there's a charge for Access Control and Service Bus.

You cannot host Azure AppFabric on-premise.